# wkhtmltopdf footer-html encoding utf-8

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf --encoding utf-8 is not working for --footer-html.

I am using the following command. Both HTML files are also in utf8 format.

```
wkhtmltopdf  --dpi 120 -O Portrait --encoding 'utf-8' --footer-html /tmp/testFooter.html  /tmp/testMain.html  /tmp/testPDF.pdf
```

Both files have french characters. But in pdf footer have bad characters.

```
<html>
     <head>
        <title></title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <div style="width:95%;font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;">
    <div style="border-top: 1px solid black;width: 100%;text-align: center;">
    test - Guérin 691BANNE - FRANCE - SA au capital 0 Euros -737 729 - Téléphone :  86 03</div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Following image is output
[image]

Comment: Can you give us a small example of a  HTML file that does not work? I don't even define --encoding and everything still works for me.

Comment: I have only now found your post. I posted about the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387826/print-utf-chars-in-page-header-footer-with-wkhtmltopdf, but I am not giving the html with --footer-html option. Instead I was specifying it with --footer-left. Actually --header-left, but not important.
I was going to try with --footer-html next, but obviously that doesn't work too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wkhtmltopdf - encoding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859872/wkhtmltopdf-encoding-issue)

Answer (score 105):

Try adding the following line in the HTML head element of the footer:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixed it

Comment: here is output example https://gist.github.com/equivalent/27d4abbb78ea991778316526f87fff94

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have specific font installed there. I need Hindi (Indian Language) on my PDF files. putting meta tag had not solved my problem. So i installed hindi fonts on my debian box by

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
```

Comment: The image clearly shows it's a simple encoding problem, as explained in the most-upvoted answer.

Comment: For me, i had similar problem. I tried suggested solutions but it did not work for me. That's how i came to know i need to install new font. now without suggested metatag, i can print foreign language which i was interested in.

Comment: You may have had a *similar* problem, but it's not so similar that this answer would solve the issue that is being asked here.

Comment: For HINDI (Indic) font I have to install Mangal font.