# UTF-8 Special Characters not working in header file

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am facing a strange issue with wkhtmltopdf. While in Footer and Content, all special characters are shown as supposed, in the header file, they don't show up or get replaced by blocks with a question mark. All of the three files are built the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there some kind of trick to tell the header to use utf-8 to?
Btw, I am already telling wkhtmltopdf to use utf-8 not only as meta but also in the script call:

```
--encoding utf-8
```

EDIT: I am using an html-header (as you can see on the code I posted). Every 3 HTML files are built the same way. But while it is working in the content, the header don't likes my special chars. Maybe it is a problem that the content in the header comes from a $_POST variable while in the content, the text is built out of the db?

Comment: are you using a text or a html header? If text: try setting the header-font to a font that can handle the characters; if html: try explicitly including the encoding in the html.

Comment: Is your header file definitely UTF-8 encoded in addition to the charset being declared?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this=> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455779/wkhtmltopdf-footer-html-encoding-utf-8?rq=1